# How to count the number of shared values in column b between every pair of values in column a?

Tags: algorithm, pandas, dataframe, graph, merge

I have a data frame with 2 columns 'la' and 'lb'. I want to count the number of shared lb values between every pair of 'la' values, with condition not counting between same 'la' values and not counting a pair twice unordered, e.g., not counting (1, 1), not counting (2, 1) if counted (1, 2). You can think of this as building an undirected, not self-looped, weighted graph between 'la' nodes.

```
d = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0], [2, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1]], columns=['la', 'lb'])
d
Out[26]: 
   la  lb
0   1   0
1   2   0
2   1   1
3   2   1

# The final result I want:
   la_x  la_y  count_shared_lb
0     1     2   2
1   ...   ... ...
.
.
.
```

Currently I am doing a merge, then groupby and count.

```
dd= d.merge(d, left_on='lb', right_on='lb')
dd
Out[27]: 
   la_x  lb  la_y
0     1   0     1
1     1   0     2
2     2   0     1
3     2   0     2
4     1   1     1
5     1   1     2
6     2   1     1
7     2   1     2

dd.groupby(['la_x', 'la_y'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count_shared_lb')
Out[30]: 
   la_x  la_y  count_shared_lb
0     1     1                2
1     1     2                2
2     2     1                2
3     2     2                2
```

But I'm stuck here because I cannot filter out unwanted rows. More important, the data frame is so large that merging runs out of memory.

So I have 2 questions: Is there a way to accomplish the result without using merge? If not, is there a way to filter out unwanted rows (before merging is prefered)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to two, you can shrink `d` a bit in advance by dropping all rows with a unique value for `lb`. This *won't* solve the merge problem but should shrink the initial footprint a bit.

```
counts = d.lb.value_counts()
uniq_lbs = set(counts[counts < 2].index)
d = d[~d.lb.isin(uniq_lbs)]
```

As to one, the dead simplest answer would be to just drop all rows where `la_x >= la_y`, since that should cover all of the redundant counts. That said, it would probably be a lot more efficient if you instead did an number of smaller merges via a for-loop instead of one big merge and then concatenating your results.This should let you skip matching things twice over in the first place.

```
la_vals = sorted(df.la.unique())
d_list = []
for i in range(len(la_vals)-1):
    left_d = d.loc[d.la == la_vals[i], :]
    right_d = d.loc[d.la.isin(la_vals[i:]), :]
    d_list.append(left_d.\
                         merge(right_d, left_on = 'lb', right_on = 'lb').\
                         loc[:, ['la_x', 'la_y']])

final_d = pd.concat(d_list)
```

You should be able to parallelize the above without too much trouble, since nothing in `d` is being altered. If you do so, consider doing the counts within each process and then aggregating all of the `la_x, la_y, count` triples at the end using a sum.

That said, depending on the specifics of your case the biggest problem here is that you'll do a lot of worst case similarity matching - checking values that have nothing in common whatsoever. You might want to take a look at some graph libraries like [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/) or [`igraph`](http://igraph.org/redirect.html) to see if a graph algorithm will help you a bit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the order of `la_x` & `la_y` out, this solves many problems. The real data is string so I did not think about it. The for-loop is a good solution, I will try to parallelize it. `lb` is unlikely to appear only once, so the first trick will not help much. Can you give me more detailed direction on graph tools, what graph algorithm should I look for here?

Comment: I was stuck in pandas and try to find a pandas' way to do it. Is there a pandas feature that replaces the for-loop above?

Comment: I implemented the for-loop solution on real data. It works well except that it takes way too long compared to direct pandas merge. I'm parallelizing it to see if that helps. Thanks.